# Como colocar borda zigzag em uma imagem usando css?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de adicionar uma borda zig-zag **transparente** para imagens em meu site.

Nesta imagem eu fiz uma mera demonstração no Photoshop:

[image: o que eu quero]

Obs.: a borda rosa da imagem quero que seja transparente.

Por enquanto este é meu código:

```
.tawcvs-swatches .swatch {

    -webkit-border-radius: 10%;
    -moz-border-radius: 10%;
    border-radius: 10%;


    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;     
    margin-right: 15px
    cursor: pointer;
    /* border: 3px solid transparent; */
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cara isso é meio trabalhoso, pois vc meio que precisa de uns "números mágicos" (números em px fixos), pois só assim vc consegue ajustar precisamente esse picote na imagem.

O que eu vou fazer é um gradiente desse tipo por cima da imagem que vai se repetir no `X` e `Y`, onde vou usar `position`, `repeat` e `size` para controlar o picote. Imagine que esses dois "triângulos" vai se repetir pelos eixos `X` e `Y` dando a impressão do picote total como vc vai ver abaixo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer isso eu usei uma série de gradientes em `45°`, na verdade não em `45°` o tempo inteiro (-45, 135, 225...), mas ângulos que sempre cortem um quadrado em `X` de um vértice ao outro. Além disso, tb precisei usar `background-position`, e `size` e `repeat` para controlar a posição, direção e tamanho desses picotes. Vale resaltar que criei todos esse gradiente em um *pseudo-elemento* `::after` no *container* que tem a tag `img` dentro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o resultado final com o código referente as imagens acima. Só que aqui eu coloquei a cor do gradiente igual a cordo do fundo que é branco, dando a impressão do picote transparente.

```css
.tawcvs-swatches.swatch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}
.swatch::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(135deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(-135deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(135deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px),
        linear-gradient(225deg, #fff 0px, #fff 10px, transparent 10px);
    background-position: 
        0 -5px, 
        10px -5px, 
        0 45px, 
        10px 45px,
        -5px 0px,
        -5px 0px,
        45px 0px,
        45px 0px;
    background-size: 
        10px 20px,
        10px 20px,
        10px 20px,
        10px 20px,
        20px 10px,
        20px 10px,
        20px 10px,
        20px 10px;
    background-repeat:
        repeat-x,
        repeat-x,
        repeat-x,
        repeat-x,
        repeat-y,
        repeat-y,
        repeat-y,
        repeat-y;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

/* para abrir a trama do picote ajustei a posição dos gradiente mais para fora*/
.swatch:nth-child(2):after {
    background-position: 
        0px -9px,
        10px -9px,
        0 49px,
        10px 49px,
        -9px 0px,
        -9px 0px,
        49px 0px,
        49px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tawcvs-swatches swatch">
    <img src="https://fillmurray.com/60/60">
</div>

<div class="tawcvs-swatches swatch">
    <img src="https://fillmurray.com/60/60">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> "*- OBS: A borda rosa da imagem eu quero que seja transparente.*"

O que você quer é, normalmente, chamado de máscara!

Uma alternativa é utilizar um SVG. E tanto quanto a alternativa do [@hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl), dá um pouco de trabalho!

---

Primeiro, temos que, literalmente, desenhar a máscara que vamos aplicar na imagem.

A minha recomendação é que utilize o [Adobe Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/br/products/illustrator.html). Justamente porque ele já nos entrega o código do SVG **praticamente pronto** - aliás, a parte que precisamos já vem pronta...

Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes nessa parte. Vou demonstrar apenas como abstrair o "path" do SVG com o Illustrator:

[image: Illustrator-SVG]

Com o "path" em mãos, vamos aos códigos:

```css
  body {
      margin:0;
  }
  .clip-svg {
      width: 128px;
      height: 128px;
      -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
      clip-path: url(#myClip);
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>

        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XUR1o5Q.png" class="clip-svg">

        <svg width="0" height="0">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="myClip">
                    <polygon points="128,36 121,29 128,22 121,15 128,8 121,1 121,1 120,0 113,7 106,0 99,7 92,0 85,7 78,0 71,7 64,0 57,7 50,0 43,7
                        36,0 29,7 22,0 15,7 8,0 7,1 1,7 0,8 7,15 0,22 7,29 0,36 7,43 0,50 7,57 0,64 7,71 0,78 7,85 0,92 7,99 0,106 7,113 0,120 7,127
                        7,127 8,128 15,121 22,128 29,121 36,128 43,121 50,128 57,121 64,128 71,121 78,128 85,121 92,128 99,121 106,128 113,121
                        120,128 127,121 127,121 128,120 121,113 128,106 121,99 128,92 121,85 128,78 121,71 128,64 121,57 128,50 121,43  "/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
        </svg>

    </body>
</html>
```

Observe que não utilizamos o SVG por completo. Apenas o `clipPath`, através do seu *ID*: `myClip`. Logo, no CSS, *linkamos* esse *ID* na propriedade `clip-path`.

Atente-se na estrutura do SVG:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <!-- aqui entra o path vindo do SVG pelo Illustrator -->
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

A pesar de ser um excelente recurso, tem bastante problemas quanto à compatibilidade. Confira no [CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

> Esta artimanha e muito mais está em [CSS-TRICKS - Clipping and Masking in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) (em inglês, mas de fácil interpretação).

---

Todo material desta resposta está disponível no meu [GitHub/lipespry](https://github.com/lipespry/lsi-sopt/tree/master/CSS/como-colocar-borda-zigzag-em-uma-imagem-usando-css%5B367271%5D).

Comment: Legal a solução tb, e o artigo é bem interessante e de 2014! CSS é muito pouco aproveitado... uma pena

Comment: Cara, o SVG em si é pouco aproveitado. Até porque os navegadores não estão dando total atenção a ele... Ainda que seja de 2014, tem alguns navegador que ainda não tem boa compatibilidade com SVG. Isento, claro, o IE pelo fato de não ser um navegador. kk